# Flutter iOS Rich Push Notification Image not display

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Flutter Push Notification

I implemented Push Notification and notification has image link in Flutter.
In Android, The image display in Notification center automatically with notification details.
**In iOS, The image does not display in Notification center but only notification details display in Notification center.**

please see format of Push notification. Curl through, Php developer is sending notification. I am getting notification successfully but image not display automatically at iOS side and, in Android image is display automatically
I already add "mutable-content": true and,
already tried to add "mutable-content": true in notification block but not getting success

```
{
"to": "device token",
"mutable-content": true,
"notification": {
    "title": "Note 3",
    "body": "11:41",
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "image": "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
    
},
"data": {
    "notification_type": "Nice Thoughts",
    "post_details": {
        "message": "hello",
        "color": "#e0e0e0",
        "url": "www.recurpost.com",
        "img_url": "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
        "video_url": "",
        "name": "abc xyz"
    }
},
"priority": "high"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a notification service extension as described [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#advanced-optional-allowing-notification-images)

Answer (score 0):

The Following steps worked for me:

Step 1 - [Add a notification service extension](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-1---add-a-notification-service-extension)

Step 2 - [Add Target to Podfile](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-2---add-target-to-the-podfile)

Step 3 - [Use Extension Helper](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-3---use-the-extension-helper)

`NotificationService.swift` in Swift:

```
//
//  NotificationService.swift
//  RichNotification
//

import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        guard let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent,
              let attachmentURLAsString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["image"] as? String,
              let attachmentURL = URL(string: attachmentURLAsString) else {
            return
        }
        
        downloadImageFrom(url: attachmentURL) { (attachment) in
            if let attachment = attachment {
                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            }
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
    
    private func downloadImageFrom(url: URL, with completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationAttachment?) -> Void) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (downloadedUrl, response, error) in
            // 1. Test URL and escape if URL not OK
            guard let downloadedUrl = downloadedUrl else {
                completionHandler (nil)
                return
            }
            // 2. Get current's user temporary directory path
            var urlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory ())
            // 3. Add proper ending to url path, in the case jpg (The system validates the content of attached files before scheduling the corresponding notification request. If an attached file is corrupted,
            let uniqueURLEnding = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString + ".jpg"
            urlPath = urlPath.appendingPathComponent (uniqueURLEnding)
            // 4. Move downloadedUrl to newly created urlPath
            try? FileManager.default.moveItem(at: downloadedUrl, to: urlPath)
            // 5. Try adding getting the attachment and pass it to the completion handler
            do {
                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment (identifier: "picture", url: urlPath, options: nil)
                completionHandler(attachment)
            }
            catch {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

extension UNNotificationRequest {
    var attachment: UNNotificationAttachment? {
        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["image"] as? String, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: attachmentURL)!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? UNNotificationAttachment(data: imageData, options: nil)
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    convenience init(data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
        let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
    }
}
```

cURL to send push notification via Firebase/FCM

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' \
--header 'Authorization: key=<YOUR FCM KEY>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "to": "fcm token for device or channel id",
    "content_available": true,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification With Image",
        "mutable-content": true,
        "body": "Test Message "
    }, 
    "data": {
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg"
    }
}'
```